# 【Rails】How to turn a hash in an array with each in erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

### Want to achieve

ruby 2.6.5
rails 6.0.3

Thank you for your interest.
I am creating a web app in rails.
I was wondering if you could tell me how to join multiple tables together and then do a repeat each for each element in each.

### Details

From the table below, we want to get the tasks related to the user and the information related to the tasks (the solution and the name of the company that has the solution) and put them in a hash in the array.

I want to output the array we have created in this way, one at a time, using each in erb.

(I couldn't figure out how to turn a task in EACH and still output the company name and other information associated with the task in EACH.)

**Like this**

```
A suitable solution for mike task "task1
・ Company name:Dcompany Solution:「solution2」
・ Company name:Ccompany Solution:「solution3」

A suitable solution for mike task "task1
・ Company name:Acompany Solution:「solution1」
```

##### Tables

users table

```
|id|name|
| 1|mike|
| 2|bob |
```

tasks table

```
|id|task_name|user_id|
| 1|task1    |      1|
| 2|task2    |      1|
| 3|task3    |      2|
```

recommends table

```
|id|task_id|solution_id|
| 1|      1|          2|
| 2|      1|          3|
| 3|      2|          1|
```

solutions table

```
|id|solution_name|company_id|
| 1|    solution1|         1|
| 2|    solution2|         4|
| 3|    solution3|         3|
```

companies table

```
|id|name    |
| 1|Acompany|
| 2|Bcompany|
| 3|Ccompany|
| 4|Dcompany|
```

### Tried

First, I was able to join the tables as shown below, with the data I wanted as a single table.
However, I couldn't figure out how to extract the data from here and how to turn it around with each, so I gave up.

```
tasks = user.eager_load(:tasks)
tasks = tasks.eager_load(:recommends)
tasks = tasks.eager_load(recommends: :solutions)
tasks = tasks.eager_load(recommends: {solutions: :companies })
```

Answer (score 0):

This is approximately how I was able to get the ideal value.

```
infos = []

users.each do |user|
  info = {}
  temporary_array = []
  user.companies.each do |company|
  end
  info[:detail] = temporary_array
  infos << info
end
```